# SSLv2_server_method apache php5 error

Tags: php5, apache-2.4, debian-wheezy

I tried to load the php module in my apache server and this error came up

httpd: Syntax error on line 152 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_server_method

Any ideas?

System: Debian 7.4 Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 i686 GNU/Linux

PHP Version:5.5.11

OpenSSL Version: 1.0.1g

Apache Version: 2.4.9

All programms were compiled and installed from source

My `/etc/ld.so.conf` file:

```
/usr/local/openssl/lib
/usr/local/mysql/lib
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

Output from `ldd /urs/local/apache/modules/libphp5.so`:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77c9000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb6e46000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb6e32000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb6e28000)
libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0xb6a83000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb6a59000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb6a40000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xb6878000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xb6813000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb67ed000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb67e9000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1 (0xb67d2000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0xb667e000)
ibpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb66$
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb6500000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77ca000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6414000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb63f7000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0xb63d0000)
```

If you need any further information please let me know.

Comment: Where'd you get the php module? Source? Package manager?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your php5 module could be linked to the wrong OpenSSL library dynamically.

You can check with `ldd php5.so` to see how the library loader resolves dynamic links from the php5 module.

If it links to incorrect library, then you have to check your library paths and ensure that the OpenSSL 1.0.1g is in a directory in library path, and that the path is before Debian's `libssl` package's library path.

After reconfiguring, you can run `ldconfig` to update library search paths.